# Windows 10 search opening in full screen (win+q)

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, windows-search

I have noticed recently that sometimes my Windows 10 search menu (the one that is opened using <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>) opens in full screen as you can see in the image below (large image):

[image: Search menu fills the entire screen blocking everything else with black background]

When I open the start menu on its own using just <kbd>WIN</kbd> and then again use <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> it opens like it should as in the image below:

[image: Correct view of search menu not filling entire screen]

From then on it is fine. Does anyone have an idea what is causing this? Is this deliberate?

Comment: I have had this problem since updating to v. 2004. I tried to search for others regarding this before but Google has so many links for other problems/bugs. This is a bug and AFAIK, MS hasn't confirmed it anywhere that I can find. The only solace is that the issue fixes itself after a couple of searches in Windows.

Comment: After the latest updated (KB4601319) it no longer appears in full screen when the start menu has not yet been upened, however it appears in the wrong corner (top of the screen). I guess thats progress :)

Comment: This seems to be fixed in Windows 11.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this exact same problem as well, at first I thought perhaps an update corrupted something (?) so I tried 'sfc /scannow' in cmd. Did not help.

What my problem (and fix) was: I had the 'search' option/icon on the taskbar set to 'Hidden'. So after I switched that to 'Show search icon' it no longer showed the fullscreen variant when using <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd>. Howto: right-click on taskbar, in that menu go to 'Search' and in there select 'Show search icon', voila!

I hope this helps, at least your screenshot shows there is no search icon on your taskbar..

Comment: Indeed, then it is reasonably sized again, still seems to be a bug of windows. I think I will keep it hidden because I hate having stuff in the taskbar I dont need :(

Comment: You didn't have a problem. Having the search icon hidden is a valid feature Microsoft included and shouldn't have to be disabled to get a bug fixed. This is a bug and what you have provided is simply a work-around, not a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Also, what fixed this for me, Immediately after the update I had this problem.  I moved my windows bar from the right pane back to the left, then back to the right (my personal side 3 screens) and it immediately fixed it.  Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

After the 20H2 update in Windows 10, I got this problem and making the search icon visible was the possible solution. Idk how this happens to be a bug or did files corrupt during the update. This is very much annoying especially with the touchpad features to windows search. I accidentally tap with 3 fingers and the search bar goes up full screen.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1108439)